# How can I view the Demon Sword events?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia-mk2

To get the Conquest Ending you need to view 3 "demon sword rumor" events in 3 of the towns. From what I've heard these locations are:

> Slayer in Lastation, Magicom Mama in Lowee, and Big Adventurer in Leanbox)

I've heard mixed reports of whether they show up before or during Chapter 5 (unfortunately my current save is chapter 5 but I have a backup in chapter 4), but I haven't been able to reliably find these characters before or after chapter 5. I've seen Magicom Mama before (I'd swear it was during chapter 5 actually) but now that I want to get this ending I can't find any of them in either chapter 4 or 5.

Is there some trick to getting these NPCs to appear on the Chirper or is it just random chance? If it's random, do I just exit/enter town until I see the NPCs or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for those NPCs to be available at all, you need at least 55% shares in the capital city for that nation to be for that nation. So Lastation needs 55% Lastation shares, and so on and so forth. This is required just to have the person show up at all, and can be done as early as chapter 2.

Second, each town divides its NPC set in two halves, and at any time you enter town, only one half can have their chirper checked. Unfortunately this is random. So you'll possibly still need to enter and exit the town repeatedly in order to access the chirper event, even if the NPC is definitely there.

Comment: Ahah, that would be why I only saw one last playthrough. The part about it being before chapter 5 only must be bunk then, right? I only got 55% changes after starting chapter 5 last time

Comment: No, chapter 5 is the limit by which you need to see these events to actually progress towards that ending. You can still see the events after chapter 5 (in my first run, I saw the Lastation and Leanbox ones in chapter 2 but didn't see the Lowee one until chapter 6), it just won't do anything for you.

Comment: Arg, that sounds convoluted enough to be correct